# Returning back to the viewController with segues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode4.2

This is my Hierarchy

```
Navigation Controller  --> Login Controller View --- > Register Controller View
                       --> My Small Internal LeaderBoard View
```

Now I am using `segues (Push)` to go to either `LoginControllerView` or `LeaderBoardView`

Once I am on `LoginControllerView` and then `RegisterControllerView` I am using this code

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]
```

However instead of returning me to `LoginControllerView` it is returning me back to `NavigationController`.

How can I return to my `LoginController`

I am transitioning from Login to Register through PUSH segue and I have named the segue as "Register"

From Login To RegisterController I am using this code

```
[self PerformSegueWithIdentifier:@"Register" sender:Self]
```

However, I can see from `RegisterView` connection inspector that its viewController reference StoryBoard Segue is "Login" .. I am transitioning from Login to Register with `Register` Segue, How can my RegisterController has `Login` segue as reference?

Comment: In which class are you calling `[self dismissViewController...]`?

Comment: @DrummerB I am calling this in my RegisterControllerView

Comment: Something must be wrong with your view controller stack then. How are you pushing the login and register view controllers?

Comment: Do you have a custom saugue class in between LoginControllerView and RegisterControllerView

Comment: @DrummerB i am using simply [self performseagueWithidentifier .... sender self] and rptony, I have already mentioned that I am using push segue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not say how `RegisterControllerView` is being presented.  If it is being pushed on the navigation controller stack, then why not call:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If you are doing something special, then you need to say what special thing you are doing.

Also, note that if you find where a view controller is trying to dismiss itself, then you should at minimum revisit your design to see if that's really the best thing to do.  A view controller may not know how it was presented, so it may not know the best way to dismiss itself either.

Comment: kindly review my edit. My reference segue is showing to be login, i think that's the problem but how can this be possible?

Comment: OK It seems that I changed the segue from PUSH To Modal and now it works fine. Can you explain this behavior?

Comment: Because you need to use symmetric calls.  Push goes with pop, and present goes with dismiss (model segue uses present).